# HttpClient.SendAsync not sending request body

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, http-delete

I am using the ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries for .NET 4.0 (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client version 4.0.30506.0).

I need to send an HTTP DELETE with a request body. I have coded it as follows:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = Uri;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // I would normally use httpClient.DeleteAsync but I can't because I need to set content on the request.
    // For this reason I use httpClient.SendAsync where I can both specify the HTTP DELETE with a request body.
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, string.Format("myresource/{0}", sessionId))
      {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"some-key", "some-value"}};
        Content = new ObjectContent<IDictionary<string, object>>(data, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
      };
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    // code elided
}
```

Per Fiddler, the request body is never serialized:

`DELETE http://localhost:8888/myApp/sessions/blabla123 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:8888
Content-Length: 38
Expect: 100-continue`

The response from the server:

`HTTP/1.1 408 Request body incomplete
Date: Sun, 10 Aug 2014 17:55:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 13:55:17.256
The request body did not contain the specified number of bytes. Got 0, expected 38`

I have tried a number of workarounds, including changing the type being serialized to something else, doing the serialization myself with JsonSerialize, changing the HTTP DELETE to PUT, etc...

Nothing worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the `ObjectContent` type?

Comment: BTW, have you tried using `DeleteAsync` without setting the content-type to `application-json`?

Comment: The ObjectContent generic type is IDictionary<string, object>. Essentially a set of key value pairs.

Comment: DeleteAsync does not support passing any content.

Comment: I set the Content property of the HttpRequestMessage to `new ObjectContent<IDictionary<string, object>>(data, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())`. I did try StringContent instead but that did not work either. When I'd serialized my test data to put into the string, it looked like this `{ "some-key", "some-value" }`

Comment: According to the first fiddler request, it looks like it is serializing your body: `Content-Length: 38`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59060/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-philippe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue, though it does not make sense. I noticed that if I changed my call to HTTP PUT or POST, it still failed to serialize the Content as a request body. That was rather strange as previous PUTs and POSTs were successful. After doing a ton of debugging into framework libraries (using Reflector), I finally got to the only thing left that was "different."

I am using NUnit 2.6.2. The structure of my test is:

```
[Test]
async public void Test()
{
  // successful HTTP POST and PUT calls here
  // successful HTTP DELETE with request body here (after 
  //       moving it from the TearDown below)
}

[TearDown]
async public void TerminateSession()
{
  // failed HTTP DELETE with request body here
}
```

Why does this fail in the TearDown but not in the Test itself? I have no idea. Is something going on with the TearDown attribute or with the use of the async keyword (since I await async calls)?

I am not sure what it is causing this behavior, but I do know now that I can submit an HTTP DELETE with a request body (as outlined in my code sample in the question).

Another solution that worked is as follows:

```
[Test]
async public void Test()
{
  // create and use an HttpClient here, doing POSTs, PUTs, and GETs
}

// Notice the removal of the async keyword since now using Wait() in method body
[TearDown]
public void TerminateSession()
{
  // create and use an HttpClient here and use Wait().
  httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's never quite that helpful to say, "don't do it that way", but in this case I think it makes sense to split the calls into a DELETE followed or preceeded by a POST or PUT.

The [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) doesn't explicitly opine on the matter, so technically it means that we *can*.  The other question, however, is *should* we do it.

In cases such as this I would look for other implementations to see what is the *de facto* standard.  As you've found in the .net implementation, it appears that the designers did not expect to send a body with the DELETE call.  So, let's look at another popular (and very different impl) Python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#http-verbs):

```
>>> r = requests.delete(url=url, auth=auth)
>>> r.status_code
204
>>> r.headers['status']
'204 No Content'
```

No body here other.  So, if the spec authors didn't mention it, and popular implementations assume that there's no body, then the principle of least surprise means we shouldn't do it either.

So, if you can change the API, it will be easier on clients of the API to split into two calls.  Otherwise, you'll likely have to resort to custom hackery to cram the body into a DELETE call.

The good news is that you've likely found a bug in the .net framework, which is an achievement in and of itself.  Clients advertising a non-zero Content-Length without actually sending it are broken.

Comment: Agreed, the spec is open to interpretation. And there is a bug somewhere, though it may be in NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else runs into this, one thing I've noticed that can cause this is if you set a header with a newline in it.

We had an encrypted OAuth token, which gets decrypted at runtime and set as the OAuth header on the app. The newline was encrypted into the token, so it was not obvious from looking at the configs or anything that it was there, but if you do:

```cs
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://example.com");
message.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
message.Content = new StringContent("{ \"someKey\": \"someValue\" }", Encoding.UTF8);

// note the trailing newline
message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", "my auth token\n");

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

The HTTP request will be sent, but the content will not be sent with it. There are no exceptions thrown when this happens and if you inspect the HttpRequestMessage, the content will appear to be there, but it does not actually get sent over the wire.

This happens in .NET 5 on Windows and Linux, I haven't tested it on other framework versions/platforms.